# Rspec error: No route matches {:controller=>"user"}

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

Why am I getting that/how can I get around it?

Code is:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users=User.all
  end
end
```

Spec is:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UserController do

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns @users" do
      user = User.create(:email => 'bob@test.com', :password=>'12', :password_confirmation=> '12')
      get :index
      assigns(:users).should eq([user])
    end 

    it "renders the index template" do
      get :index
      response.should render_template("index")
    end 
  end 

end

Failures:

  1) UserController GET index assigns @users
     Failure/Error: get :index
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"user"}
     # ./spec/controllers/user_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UserController GET index renders the index template
     Failure/Error: get :index
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"user"}
     # ./spec/controllers/user_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.13146 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures
```

Routes are:

```
TimeTracker::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :users

  root :to => 'users#index'

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller class name is in singular (`UserController`), it should be `UsersController`

Comment: yes that was it.  Initially I got ` uninitialized constant UsersController (NameError)` when trying that.  Turned out my controlleriyself was misnamed